# How to style reactable cell background with custom grouping select

Tags: r, reactable, htmltools

I have some data I'm trying to present using `reactable`. I am styling the background of cells based on the value. There are a number of groups in the data which are useful, but the groups themselves do not have an aggregated value that is useful.

The issue I'm facing is that when the data is grouped with the custom grouping select, the table will retain the style of the first few rows of data so the background is coloured. I would like it to be blank for the grouped row.

In the example below, when grouping by `group` you'll notice that `A` and `C` have the background coloured, inheriting the style from rows 1 and 3 in the data. I could imagine a hacky way of organizing the data so only non-stylized rows come first, but that is not really appropriate as the data would be too disorganized at initial presentation.

Is there a way to strip the style when grouped, but retain it for the rows with values?

```r
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5),
  value = rnorm(15)
)

htmltools::browsable(
  tagList(
    div(tags$label("Group by", `for` = "tab")),
    tags$select(
      id = "tab",
      onchange = "Reactable.setGroupBy('tab', this.value ? [this.value] : [])",
      tags$option("None", value = ""),
      tags$option("Group", value = "group"),
    ),

    reactable(
      data,
      columns = list(
        value = colDef(style = function(value){
          if (value < 0) list(background = "#ffa500")
        })
      ),
      defaultPageSize = 15,
      elementId = "tab"
    )
  )
)
```

[image: reactable group background style]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way using JavaScript. I've changed the variable `value` to `num` in the example below so it's more clear how to apply the function.

The grouping is done via JavaScript in the browser, so there isn't a way to control group styling in R as far as I'm aware.

```r
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 5),
  num = rnorm(15)
)

htmltools::browsable(
  tagList(
    div(tags$label("Group by", `for` = "tab")),
    tags$select(
      id = "tab",
      onchange = "Reactable.setGroupBy('tab', this.value ? [this.value] : [])",
      tags$option("None", value = ""),
      tags$option("Group", value = "group"),
    ),

    reactable(
      data,
      columns = list(
        num = colDef(style = JS("function(rowInfo) {
        var value = rowInfo.row['num']
        if (value < 0) {
          var background = '#ffa500'
        } 
        return {background: background}
      }"))
      ),
      defaultPageSize = 15,
      elementId = "tab"
    )
  )
)
```